# Adaptive Card Action Error in Outlook Desktop but not in OOTW

Tags: outlook, office365, adaptive-cards, office365connectors

I'm trying to send an adaptive card/actionable message to users in my Office 365 tenant, as a simple survey for them to fill out. I am sending the card via Microsoft Flow. The card renders perfectly in both Outlook desktop and Outlook on the Web. However, the action (HTTP POST) only works in Outlook on the Web and throws an error in Outlook desktop.

I'm using Outlook for Office 365 (ProPlus) on the Monthly Channel (targeted) version 1906. From the documentation I've seen, this should work (right?) The table here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/#release-notes shows that support was added in version 1805.

---

```
"type": "Action.Http",
"title": "Submit Event Summary",
"method": "POST",
"url": "https://prod-89.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/.../triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=1aRUE1oGrJsr4Iz31MSkWGT9G_STEVU06B8vb_D6Zns&covered={{covered.value}}&features={{features.value}}&landmines={{landmines.value}}&comments={{comments.value}}",
"body": "",
"headers": [
    {
        "name": "Authorization", "value": ""
    }
```

---

```
"$schema": "https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0"
```

Like I said, it works and submits in Outlook on the Web, but the error in Outlook Desktop is "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Flow Approval buttons in build 1906 and I'm guessing adaptive cards work similarly.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Error-responding-to-Flow-Approval-in-Outlook/m-p/305111#M25905

Comment: I hope this is the case! I'll wait for the deployed fix on the 20th. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The fix has been pushed by the Outlook team, and the error code is now more specific on my end, but still not working: "The remote endpoint returned an error (HTTP 401) Please try again later." Any idea what that could mean? It still works in Outlook on the Web but not in Outlook Desktop.

Comment: Sorry, Bryant, I didn't have a chance to look into this when you posted it.  Flow Approve & Reject buttons now work in Outlook (as of version 1907).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should note that there was also a bug with the authentication token in Outlook desktop. If you passed in a null token it would work in OOTW but not Outlook Desktop. The team is working on a fix. All I had to do to fix it was to set the token to "" rather than null.